# Sync data between two viewcontrollers to avoid creating same observer again

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my main VC I look for changes in my FB database like this:

```
ref.child("posts").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
  .......                
})
```

From this VC I can enter VC2 which is set to be "present modally" in my segue.

Now I wonder if I can pass live FB data from VC1 to VC2? I know that I can use a `segue.identifier` and pass data when I segue to the next VC but this is one time *send* only. Or should I setup a delegate to fetch data from vc1 to vc2?

So is there any way I can send data from VC1 to VC2 once a node has been updated or must I setup a new `.observe()` function in VC2?

Comment: I would like to invite you to read about singleton and to think about it in order to solve your issue :)

Comment: @AchrefGassoumi Sure, any resource you could suggest?

Comment: I think this is what you need  
https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton
, if you solved your issue i would like to see your answer if not please left a comment and i will post an answer later(now i'm working cannot do that, sorry )
Also try to read this 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1

Comment: @AchrefGassoumi thanks, but no luck so far. Right now I am looking into if I can pass the firebase listener to the next VC and dont detach it. But I have not seen any example using this way. People seem to just start a new observer in the next VC

Comment: What data is displayed in VC1 vs VC2? i.e. why do you move from one viewController to another? What's your code look like? How about a snippet of your Firebase structure so we can understand the relationship between the data?

Comment: @Jay I just need to be able to display the data live in both VC's. The code above grabs two values form my FB database and update a UILabel in my VC to whatever value it has. Right now I am making one more connection in the second VC to fetch the exact same data, and I think this is wrong

Comment: Two view controllers showing the same data is a little odd - perhaps you could update your question with your use case and a snippet of your Firebase strucure, as text please - no images.

Comment: @Jay Without going into too much detail about the app. In both VC's I am displaying coordinate numbers. Not showing them on a map just displaying the coordinate numbers. I need the coordinates live updated in both VC's. I think my quesiton is clear, I wonder what ways there is to display live data in both VC's without using multiple observers that target the same source

Comment: The singleton pattern is made exactly to solve your problem , this is absolutely wrong to invoke the database in every view controller (this could work but this is waste of time and effort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would like to remind you about the singleton design patter :
In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the **instantiation** of a class to **one object**. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to **coordinate actions** across the system.

So the first thing you need to do is to create a call that contains as a parameters the data you get from firebase, I have did the following to get the following in order to get the user data when he logged in into my app and then use these data in every part of my application (I don't have any intention to pass the data between VC this is absolutely the wrong approach )
my user class is like this :

```
import Foundation   
class User {

    static let sharedInstance = User()

    var uid: String!
    var username: String!
    var firstname: String!
    var lastname: String!
    var profilePictureData: Data!
    var email: String!
}
```

after that I have created another class FirebaseUserManager (you can do this in your view controller but it's always an appreciated idea to separate your view your controller and your model in order to make any future update easy for you or for other developer )
So my firebaseUserManager class contains something like this

```
    import Foundation
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseStorage
    protocol FirebaseSignInUserManagerDelegate: class {
        func signInSuccessForUser(_ user: FIRUser)
        func signInUserFailedWithError(_ description: String)
    }
    class FirebaseUserManager {
    weak var firebaseSignInUserManagerDelegate: FirebaseSignInUserManagerDelegate!
 func signInWith(_ mail: String, password: String) {

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: mail, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {

                self.firebaseSignInUserManagerDelegate.signInUserFailedWithError(error.localizedDescription)

                return
            }

            self.fechProfileInformation(user!)
        }
    }        

func fechProfileInformation(_ user: FIRUser) {

            var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
            ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

            let currentUid = user.uid

            ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: currentUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                if snapshot.exists() {

                    let dict = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary

                    let currentUserData = dict[currentUid] as! NSDictionary

                    let singletonUser = User.sharedInstance
                    singletonUser.uid = currentUid
                    singletonUser.email = currentUserData["email"] as! String
                    singletonUser.firstname = currentUserData["firstname"] as! String
                    singletonUser.lastname = currentUserData["lastname"] as! String
                    singletonUser.username = currentUserData["username"] as! String

                    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
                    let storageref = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://versus-a107c.appspot.com")
                    let imageref = storageref.child("images")
                    let userid : String = (user.uid)
                    let spaceref = imageref.child("\(userid).jpg")

                    spaceref.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        } else {

                            singletonUser.profilePictureData = data!

                            print(user)

                            self.firebaseSignInUserManagerDelegate.signInSuccessForUser(user)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

so basically this class contains some protocols that we would implements and two functions that manager the firebase signIn and fechProfileInformation , that will get the user information

than in my login View controller I did the following :
1 implement the protocol

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FirebaseSignInUserManagerDelegate
```

2 in the login button I did the following

```
 @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: UIButton) {



        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }

        let firebaseUserManager = FirebaseUserManager()
        firebaseUserManager.firebaseSignInUserManagerDelegate = self

        firebaseUserManager.signInWith(email, password: password)
    }
```

3 implement the protocol method :
  func signInSuccessForUser(_ user: FIRUser) {

```
   // Do something example navigate to the Main Menu 
}

func signInUserFailedWithError(_ description: String) {
    // Do something : example alert the user
}
```

So right now when the user click on the sign in button there is an object created which contains the user data save on firebase database

now comes the funny part (the answer of your question : how to get the user data in every where in the app)

in every part of my app I could make

```
print(User.sharedInstance.uid) or print(User.sharedInstance. username)
```

and I get the value that I want to.

PS : In order to use the singleton appropriately you need to make sure that you call an object when it's instantiated.