# Accessing a variable outside closure Swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have declared requestPostArray right at the beginning of the ViewController class. I'm trying to populate the requestPostArray from the database "Request Posts" and then populate the tableView from the requestPostArray. However when I print it's size it shows up to be 0. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, the entire else statement below is inside another closure.

```
else {

            ref.child("Request Posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

                // Request Post database is empty
                if count == 0 {
                    cell.nameLabel.text = "No requests so far."
                    cell.userNameLabel.isHidden = true
                    cell.numberOfRequestsLabel.isHidden = true
                }

                // Request Post data is populated
                else {

                    var requestPostArray: [RequestPost]? = []
                    self.ref.child("Request Posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                            for child in result {
                                let post = RequestPost(snapshot: child)
                                requestPostArray?.append(post)
                            }
                        }

                        else {
                            print("No Result")
                        }
                    })


                    print("RequestPostArray size = \(requestPostArray?.count ?? 90)")

                    cell.nameLabel.text = self.requestPostArray?[indexPath.row].name
                    cell.userNameLabel.text = self.requestPostArray?[indexPath.row].name
                    cell.numberOfRequestsLabel.text = self.requestPostArray?[indexPath.row].name
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what should happens because observe function is asynchronous and the rest of your code is synchronous, in addition if you remove the optional unwrap from `requestPostArray?` you will get a nil exception because the async task needs time to get executed so the compiler will execute the snyc task before it.
basically what you have to do is the following

```
 else {

                ref.child("Request Posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

                    // Request Post database is empty
                    if count == 0 {
                        cell.nameLabel.text = "No requests so far."
                        cell.userNameLabel.isHidden = true
                        cell.numberOfRequestsLabel.isHidden = true
                    }

                    // Request Post data is populated
                    else {

                        var requestPostArray: [RequestPost]? = []
                        self.ref.child("Request Posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                                for child in result {
                                    let post = RequestPost(snapshot: child)
                                    requestPostArray?.append(post)
                                }
                            }

                            else {
                                print("No Result")
                            }
print("RequestPostArray size = \(requestPostArray?.count ?? 90)")

                        cell.nameLabel.text = self.requestPostArray?[indexPath.row].name
                        cell.userNameLabel.text = self.requestPostArray?[indexPath.row].name
                        cell.numberOfRequestsLabel.text = self.requestPostArray?[indexPath.row].name
                        })



                    }
                })
            }
```

another advice think about using singleton so you can gain the reuse of your object and you will not invoke the database several time at the same method like you are doing now.

Comment: Thank you Achref! I'm relatively new to Swift so I'm not really sure what a singleton is. Could you briefly tell me what it is or point me to a link where I can find out more about it? Thanks

Comment: please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43513805/4442592 , i included a whole example , for further details i would like to invite you to read this awesome tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1

Comment: was my answer helpful ?

Comment: Yes your answer was helpful. It did work but it turns out that I have to manually set the numberOfRowsInSection() for the table to display the correct amount of rows. I'm currently trying to work on storing the number of posts in the database in a variable and then returning it in the numberOfRowsInSection() function.

Comment: this another problem, please mark this question as solved and ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

`observe` blocks are asynchronous. You're reading `requestPostArray` before it has been modified by your `requestPostArray?.append(post)` line.

Without more context it's hard to know how you want to be populating values on this `cell` object but if you need "Request Posts" then you have to wait until you've been able to obtain them.

Comment: Thank you Jonah! I do the "Request Posts" database. I have created a custom type object called "RequestPost" and I want to store all the children in the database to an array of RequestPost called requestPostArray whose members are going to populate the table cells. 

How exactly do I "wait until you've been able to obtain them". Is there a specific function which fires only once the block finishes executing?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make async queries inside a table view datasource's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. That's not going to work because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` needs an immediate result and won't wait for your query to run. Instead consider how `FUITableViewDataSource` (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI) is designed to solve this problem.