# Swift 3.0 iOS10 Passing Async data through a segue sender for Firebase

Tags: ios, json, swift, asynchronous, uistoryboardsegue

I have a log in page that collects a username and password. On submit, Its sends to the database to retrieve our servers access key. I do this through an asynchronous JSON POST using session.dataTask. When I retrieve the JSON Object I parse the key out of it. I want to pass it to the next page, retrieve a firebase token and then send both pieces of data back to the server for DB storage. I have created a "prepare for segue" function that collects the variable and passes it to a variable on the next page. I believe I am not setting up the sequence of events correctly or that the data isn't making it out of the Async container. Can someone have a look at these two files and see where I am getting it wrong?

Here is the first page I want to segue away from after making the REST web service call...

loginVC.swift:

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var validationBox: UITextView!
    @IBAction func logInAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let user = username.text, !user.isEmpty else {
            validationBox.text = "Please enter valid credentials"
            return
        }
        guard let pass = password.text, !pass.isEmpty else {
            validationBox.text = "Please enter valid credentials"
            return
        }

        let params = ["sUser": username.text!, "sPass": password.text!]

        let url = URL(string: "restWebServiceURL")!
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                if let parsedJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                    let parsedData = parsedJSON["d"] as! [String:Any]
                    let key = parsedData["key"] as! String
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(key)
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "FirebaseVC", sender: key)
                    }

                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello!")
    }
    func sayGoodbye() {
        print("Goodbye!")
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        validationBox.text = "Ready..."
        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if let FirebaseInit = segue.destination as? FirebaseVC {
                if let sKey = sender as? String {
                    print("prepare - " + sKey)
                    FirebaseInit.sessionKey = sKey
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Here is the page I want to go to to receive the data access key ...

FirebaseVC.swift:

```
import UIKit

class FirebaseVC: UIViewController {

    private var _sessionKey = String()

    var sessionKey : String {
        get { return _sessionKey }
        set { _sessionKey = newValue }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var sessionKeyTestBox: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(_sessionKey)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Feel free to suggest a better way to pass the data to the next page. Thanks...

Comment: PS : we don't say in swift on submit, this is not wrong but it just doesn't exist, anyway I would like to invite you to think about using some design pattern like singleton : the logic is so simple you instantiate a class with data you get from you server and you call this object whenever you need it , and since one user could connect at once (singleton will guarantee that there is only one instance of that class )

Comment: I don't like the use of singletons, just my personal opinion....I would change `if let FirebaseInit = segue.destination as? FirebaseVC {` to `if (segue.destination.isKind(of: FirebaseVC.self)) { let vc = segue.destination as! FireBaseVC` but those are pretty much the same...can you set a breakpoint inside of the prepareForSegue, and make sure your sKey is being cast to a string correctly?

Comment: Well, I built the Android app and the web app app using that model so I am not opposed to it at all. Can you provide some guidance?

Comment: @JacobBoyd When I submit (press login) xcode shows a breakpoint at self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "FirebaseVC", sender: key)

Comment: I disabled that breakpoint, It performs the segue and goes to the next page but no data is passed...

Comment: @AchrefGassoumi This is a network intensive app so I agree with you on implementation of Singleton into the app. However, I still need to learn how to do this so for this SO post is concerned could you please help with this particular problem?

Comment: please take a look at this answer , i hope it will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/43513805/4442592

Comment: @AchrefGassoumi Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was correct in my assumption the the chain of events was off. Following the model suggested by @achrefGassoumi, I moved the datatask to a Singleton Service here:

```
import Foundation

struct CallWebService {

    static let sharedInstance = CallWebService()

    func logInToCaduceus(u: String, p: String, completion: @escaping (_ sKey: String) -> ()) {
        let params = ["sUser": u, "sPass": p]

        let url = URL(string: "https://telemed.caduceususa.com/ws/telemed.asmx/telemedLogin")!
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                if let parsedJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                    let parsedData = parsedJSON["d"] as! [String:Any]
                    let key = parsedData["key"] as! String
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(key)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

Then my two controllers look like this:

LoginVC

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.destination.isKind(of: FirebaseVC.self)) {
            let vc = segue.destination as! FirebaseVC
            if let sKey = sender as? String {
                vc.sessionKey = sKey
            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var validationBox: UITextView!
    @IBAction func logInAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let user = username.text, !user.isEmpty else {
            validationBox.text = "Please enter valid credentials"
            return
        }
        guard let pass = password.text, !pass.isEmpty else {
            validationBox.text = "Please enter valid credentials"
            return
        }

        CallWebService.sharedInstance.logInToCaduceus(u: username.text!, p: password.text!, completion: {(sessionKey: String) -> Void in
                print(sessionKey)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "FirebaseVC", sender: sessionKey)
            }
        )

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //validationBox.textAlignment = .center
        validationBox.text = "Ready..."
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

AND THE receiving FirebaseVC

```
import UIKit

class FirebaseVC: UIViewController {

    private var _sessionKey = String()

    var sessionKey : String {
        get { return _sessionKey }
        set { _sessionKey = newValue }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var sessionKeyTestBox: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sessionKeyTestBox.text = _sessionKey
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Excuse my (non-swift) Javascript terminology but essentially I moved the data call into a service and then place a callback method in the service with the completion method to ensure the the performSegue doesn't fire until the data has been received and parsed out. So when i submit the log in form data to the server the segue doesn't fire until that async call has been completed.

Comment: Great work and nice to hear that :), I have the following remarks :
- You could add a model layer like a class that you instantiate with the data that you wish to get access in other VC, maybe 
- "ensure that the performSegue doesn't fire until the data has been received" is not really a problem because if you add a model layer like I told you when the object you create from the class is not nil than the login is succeed than you can continue further with application.
- Singleton is one of the very needed Design pattern in swift so I would like to invite you to continue reading about it.

Comment: Can you add data from the appDelegate to that model?

Comment: it's simply the MVC as far as I know you cannot: You need just to get the variable in the view controller from the appDelegate initialise your model class in the View controller (Create an object over it) with the data you want. 
If you implement the MVC correctly you can easily maintain or update your code in the future and it will much more understandable.

Comment: I don't want to make my appDelegate a sharedInstance though.

Comment: From what I can tell I just create a Singleton Class and use it as if I would sessionStorage in JS. Is this a fair assumption? Does the class stick around if the device restarts or if the app is force closed? (like localStorage)

Comment: First of all please mark this question as solved since you have solve it, so other people may find your answer and it would helpful for them.
and concerning you question yesterday we can get variables inside appDelegate inside the model class next thing I would like to remind you that there is a huge difference between the logic of javascript and any other Object oriented language

Comment: following my previous comment when the user login, the data get parsed and the object is created when he logout, make sure that you destroy all the object that you have created, when the application is in foreground , the instance of the classes that you have instantiated will continue being allocated in the memory for that you will not get any nil

Comment: Concept is basically easy : user login -> data gets parsed -> object created -> you can get access to the object that you have created anywhere in you app -> the object is saved in the RAM memory of the phone -> user logout  -> object destroyed or overrided.